# java, best API jar

Tags: java, api, servlets

I'm building one API using javax.ws.rs-api(2.1.1) and com.sun.jersey (1.18.1) but it causes one Exception. Reading some threads it seems like one of both includes one class that is part of the other and this raises this Exception.
After some tries I'm still stucked on find how to fix it but then another question came to my brain, Is this the best API class for building servlets? So my question is if somebody can provide his experience and can say that continue using those libraries is the best option (and then fight for fixing this Exception) or can suggest better options.

I'm not using Spring neither Hibernate and those are not the option, I build my own Servlet from scratch ... yes ... I have my reasons ....

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS is an API specification that defines what an implementing framework must achieve. Jersey is one such framework as is Spring. It's likely that Jersey contains all the JAX-RS classes and so you won't need to import both (assuming you're using something like Maven which pulls in transitive dependencies for you)

Comment: Thanks @tomgeraghty3, Do you use Jersey? Spring? something else?

Comment: I use Jersey with Spring Boot (Spring Boot just for the core Spring features and built in TomCat instance etc. rather than the Spring MVC side)